# Can Google Cloud speech Api live stream phone call audio?

Tags: android, audio, speech-to-text, phone-call

I want to translate audio of live phone call to text without pre-recording it. I am using Google cloud speech Api and right now I am recording the phone call and then passing the recorded file to the Api. this is taking too much time delay. is there a way to make use of this Api without pre-recording. Is there a way to live stream phone calls audio to text?  or is there any other better solution?  please help. thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Jana, you can try IBM Watson API, we have many clients streaming telephony speech in real time to our speech to text service. They are very happy :)  -  https://speech-to-text-demo.mybluemix.net/

Comment: can this be commercially used?

Comment: You have mentioned "streaming telephony speech in real time ", but as per the link, it says, the audio has to recorded though chunk by chunk. is it true?  also, wont there be delay or loss of data if we record chunk by chunk and get the response back?.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to translate live streaming using google speech api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44177012/how-to-translate-live-streaming-using-google-speech-api)

Comment: @PitDigger duplicate has an answer, this one doesn't ;)