# How to translate live streaming using google speech api?

Tags: php, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

This is the Google Speech API docs: https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/sync-recognize

I trried this API for 2 weeks, but still can't solve my main purpose (translate live streaming).

I'm using PHP. (other language suggestion is allowed, I will find by myself)

> What I can do in my 2 weeks:

1. Synchronous Speech Recognition (<=1min)
2. Asynchronous Speech Recognition (>1min and <=80min). **Note**: i can modify this to accept 3hours video.
3. Live speech recognition from mic : https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html
4. **UPDATE:** Perform streaming API with audio less than 6sec duration.

> What can't I do is:

1. How to translate live streaming.  ex: radio streaming (delay is allowed)
2. How to Translate when video/audio playing. (delay is allowed)

**UPDATE:**

I also ask the question on google github too. but since no answer, i ask [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/issues/375).

**Summary:**

I can perform speech streaming but only with 6 second audio. This is not like what i expected. My expectation is to recognize unlimited duration (seems we dont know when radio streaming will end).

Thank for any help. i very appreciate it

**UPDATE:**

To approve that I can't use video longer than 6sec. so i write this:

I try this video [interview.mp4](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwP1dgw0cT3ZZFVTc0NRVzUwVk0/view?usp=sharing) and convert it with ffmpeg to [interview.flac](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwP1dgw0cT3ZMnV1V1JtQ1JTRWc/view?usp=sharing) using this `ffmpeg -i interview.mp4 -c:a flac -ar 16000 -ac 1 -sample_fmt s16 interview.flac`.

i use this [library](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/api) to transcribe the video using this command:

`php speech.php transcribe --encoding FLAC --language-code en-US --sample-rate 16000 --stream interview.flac`

and the result is:

```
  [Google\GAX\ApiException]
  Invalid 'audio_content': too long.
```

it cant be too long, because the video duration is only 48 sec. this is the meta from ffmpeg result:

```
Output #0, flac, to 'interview.flac':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.72.101
    Stream #0:0(und): Audio: flac, 16000 Hz, mono, s16, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      encoder         : Lavc57.92.100 flac
size=     810kB time=00:00:48.01 bitrate= 138.1kbits/s speed= 108x
video:0kB audio:801kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.019650%
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use the [`StreamingRecognize` API call](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/streaming-recognize).  You can find an example of doing that in PHP [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php/blob/master/Speech/src/SpeechClient.php).

Comment: thank you blambert, i upvoted your help. but, please looks my update.. i have miss information before. sorry.

Comment: i just dont know how to implemented that in real streaming. i just know how to send 6second audio to speech streaming api

Comment: The streaming API has a 60 second limit, not 6, so you should be able to stream up to 60 seconds of audio.  Are you getting an error message after 6 seconds?

Comment: look my update. can u try my file bro? i give up. no clue  ><

Comment: Getting 404 on the link

Comment: fixed the link @Amarja